# ThreeJS: applying edge geometry to ArrowHelper

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to create an arrow using ArrowHelper in ThreeJS:

```
let arrow = new THREE.ArrowHelper(direction.normalize(), new THREE.Vector3(), length, color, headLength, headWidth);
```

Also I want to use a separate color for edges. I realize that I need to use THREE.EdgesGeometry, but how to apply it I don't quite understand. Could anybody help me?

**Update**
sorry for confusion, I thought the arrow uses pyramid, not cone. Is there a way to replace cone with pyramid and use different color for edges?

**Update**

Thank you all for your answers, they were really helpful. I ended up with creating custom arrow class (copied most of the code from ArrowHelper):

```
class CustomArrow extends THREE.Object3D {

    constructor( dir, origin, length, color, edgeColor, headLength, headWidth ) {

        super();
        // dir is assumed to be normalized

        this.type = 'CustomArrow';

        if ( dir === undefined ) dir = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 1 );
        if ( origin === undefined ) origin = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );
        if ( length === undefined ) length = 1;
        if ( color === undefined ) color = 0xffff00;
        if ( headLength === undefined ) headLength = 0.2 * length;
        if ( headWidth === undefined ) headWidth = 0.2 * headLength;

        if ( this._lineGeometry === undefined ) {
            this._lineGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
            this._lineGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], 3 ) );
            this._coneGeometry = new THREE.ConeBufferGeometry( 0.5, 1, 6);
            this._coneGeometry.translate( 0, - 0.5, 0 );
            this._axis = new THREE.Vector3();
        }

        this.position.copy( origin );

        this.line = new THREE.Line( this._lineGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: color, toneMapped: false, linewidth: 4 } ) );
        this.line.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
        this.add( this.line )

        // base material        
        this.cone = new THREE.Mesh( this._coneGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: color, toneMapped: false } ) );
        this.add(this.cone);

        // wire frame
        this.wireframe = new THREE.Mesh( this._coneGeometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { 
            color: edgeColor, 
            toneMapped: false, 
            wireframe: true,
            wireframeLinewidth: 2 } ) );
        this.add(this.wireframe);

        this.setDirection( dir );
        this.setLength( length, headLength, headWidth );
    }

    setDirection( dir ) {

        // dir is assumed to be normalized

        if ( dir.y > 0.99999 ) {

            this.quaternion.set( 0, 0, 0, 1 );

        } else if ( dir.y < - 0.99999 ) {

            this.quaternion.set( 1, 0, 0, 0 );

        } else {

            this._axis.set( dir.z, 0, - dir.x ).normalize();

            const radians = Math.acos( dir.y );

            this.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( this._axis, radians );

        }

    }

    setLength( length, headLength, headWidth ) {

        if ( headLength === undefined ) headLength = 0.2 * length;
        if ( headWidth === undefined ) headWidth = 0.2 * headLength;

        this.line.scale.set( 1, Math.max( 0.0001, length - headLength ), 1 ); // see #17458
        this.line.updateMatrix();
        
        this.cone.scale.set( headWidth, headLength, headWidth );
        this.cone.position.y = length;
        this.cone.updateMatrix();
        
        this.wireframe.scale.set( headWidth, headLength, headWidth );
        this.wireframe.position.y = length;
        this.wireframe.updateMatrix();
    }

    setColor( color ) {
        this.line.material.color.set( color );
        // this.cone.material.color.set( color );
        // this.wireframe.material.color.set( color );
    }

    copy( source ) {
        super.copy( source, false );
        this.line.copy( source.line );
        this.cone.copy( source.cone );
        this.wireframe.copy( source.wireframe );
        return this;
    }
}
```

For some reason linewidth and wireframeLinewidth don't affect lines widths. Any idea why?

Comment: When I tried using your custom class, the line in the arrow disappeared. Any idea why?

Comment: After investigating further, it's because the line `this._lineGeometry.setAttribute( 'position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], 3 ) );` is throwing an error: `this._linearGeometry.setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: Ah! I found my problem - I was using too old a version of Three JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: A pyramid is a cone with 4 radial segments, if you want that, look at how the [arrowhelper](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/ArrowHelper.js) constructs it's cone (which is with a tapered CylinderGeometry) and line based on the parameters and replace it with a cone geometry constructed as follows:

original:

```
_coneGeometry = new CylinderBufferGeometry( 0, 0.5, 1, 5, 1 );
```

new:

```
_coneGeometry = new ConeBufferGeometry( 0.5, 1, 4);
```

Then you don't have to use the EdgesGeometry, but use the wireframe material option (per @prisoner849's comment):

```
let wireframeMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: "aqua", wireframe: true});

let coneEdgeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(_coneGeometry, wireframeMaterial);
```

Original answer:

THREE.ArrowHelper consists of 2 Object3Ds: one THREE.Line for the line and one THREE.Mesh for the cone of the arrow. The Line geometry only consists of 2 points and has no edges because it is a line, but for the cone you can use:

```
let coneEdgeGeometry = new THREE.EdgesGeometry(arrow.cone.geometry);
```

Then you construct a LineSegments object with the edge geometry and the color you want:

```
let line = new THREE.LineSegments( coneEdgeGeometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } ) );
arrow.add(line);
```

If the cone edge is not showing, try setting the renderOrder of the THREE.LineSegments to -1 (this might give other issues)

Comment: `ConeBufferGeometry` is an indexed buffer geometry (where `index` contains the data about faces/triangles) and applying it "as is" to `LineSegments` leads to getting of a weird/unexpected result; whereas using with a `Mesh` and `MeshBasicMaterial({wireframe: true})` can do the trick: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/6vprmde3/

Comment: Yes thank you for this addition @prisoner849, wireframe works well if you don't want additional functionality in the future and only show the edges.

Comment: cool, that works, but in this case it becomes "transparent". How do I specify the faces color?

Comment: Wireframe: true will not show faces, so you have to have two meshes, one with wireframe: true and one without

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, but line width can't be changed in most browsers because it's not on the webgl spec, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/lineWidth and https://github.com/ryanking1809/threejs-meshline for a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colour of arrow's cone like this:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";     
  import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"; 
  
  let scene = new THREE.Scene(); 
  let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, innerWidth / innerHeight,
  1, 100); 
  camera.position.set(0, 5, 10); 
  let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); 
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight); 
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement); 
  
  new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); 
  
  scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper());
  
  // different colors 
  let ah = new THREE.ArrowHelper( 
    new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 
    new THREE.Vector3(-4, 0, 0), 
    5, 
    "magenta" /* default colour */); 
  ah.cone.material.color.set("red"); // change color of cone
  scene.add(ah); 
  
  // colourful pyramid
  let cg = new THREE.SphereBufferGeometry(0.5, 4, 2).toNonIndexed();
  let pos = cg.attributes.position;
  for (let i = 0; i < pos.count; i++){
    if (pos.getY(i) < 0) pos.setY(i, 0);
  }
  console.log(cg);
  let cls = [
    new THREE.Color("red"),
    new THREE.Color("green"),
    new THREE.Color("blue"),
    new THREE.Color("yellow")
  ]
  let colors = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    cls.forEach( (c) => {
      colors.push(c.r, c.g, c.b);
      colors.push(c.r, c.g, c.b);
      colors.push(c.r, c.g, c.b);
    });
  }
  cg.setAttribute("color", new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(colors, 3));
  
  let cm = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({vertexColors: true});
  let co = new THREE.Mesh(cg, cm);
  co.scale.set(1, 5, 1);
  scene.add(co);
  
  renderer.setAnimationLoop(()=>{ 
    renderer.render(scene, camera); 
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. That's not quite what I need. But now I realize that it's a cone, not a pyramid...Is there a way to replace cone with pyramid and use different color for edges?

Comment: @NikitaFedorov Could you provide a reference picture of the desired result?

Comment: @NikitaFedorov Updated the snippet with an example of how to create a pyramid from a sphere with painted sides.